# Failed to capturing groups with delimiter

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate my input data which should be in the below format

```
[(aa,11),(bb,22),(cc,33)]
```

I am looking for the following conditions needs to be satisfied

```
[(aa,11),(bb,22),(cc,33)] -->Valid
[(aa,11)] -->Valid
[(aa,11)(bb,22)] -->Invalid (comma missed inbetween the tuples)
[(aa,11),(bb,22),(cc,33),(dd,44),] -->Invalid (comma at the last tuple)
[,(aa,11)] ->Invalid  (comma before first tuple)
```

I wrote the regex but its not working in all the conditions bcoz i made **','** as an optional

```
^(\[(\([a-z]+,[0-9]+\),?)+\])$
```

Could someone please correct my regex?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Basically `\[\(stu,ff\)(?:,\(stu,ff\))*\]` lots of stuff. Called the basic unroll method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new matching group for every new `,(aa,11)` so that your new regex looks like this:

```
^(\[(\([a-z]+,[0-9]+\))(,\([a-z]+,[0-9]+\))*\])
```

Here you create a new group that can have 0 or more repetitions.
Check out this regexr which passes your tests: http://www.regexr.com/39tlg

Answer (score 1):

You can use a optional non-capturing group to repeat that pattern "zero or more" times.

```
^\[\([a-z]+,\d+\)(?:,\([a-z]+,\d+\))*\]$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ5rM8/2)